# Switch statements for more than one parameter

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that uses a switch statement to call methods from another class, with user input being the control for the switch, as below:

```
switch (args[0]) {
    case "bark":
        Dog.bark(); 
        break;
}
```

but would it be possible for a switch statement to work if parameters needed to be passed into bark? If bark took in, say a color, can you make the case "bark red" and pass red into the bark function which may be defined as Dog.bark(color)? Or is this not possible in java? Thank you!

edit: My actual code is a bit above this example, where certain methods that the switch statement will call can't be called without parameters. I wanted to know if it was possible for the switch statement to take in that second argument and pass it in during the cases.

Comment: What is to stop you passing an argument to `bark()`? The switch statement has nothing to do with it.

Comment: but what if I what I want to pass in to the bark() method needs to be specified by the user? That is what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
switch (args[0]) {
    case “bark”:
         if(args.length > 1) Dogs.bark(args[1]);
         else Dogs.bark();
         break;
    default:
         break;
}
```